How can I determine if the current webpage is being rendered within a CefSharp environment?
I'm encountering a peculiar issue where the same URL loads fine in Google Chrome but returns a 400 status code when accessed via CefSharp. This leads me to suspect that the website might be employing some method to detect that the page is being rendered in a CefSharp environment and consequently fails to respond normally.

What version are you using? If you are getting a 400 then they're probably looking at the request headers
